# wpf filter datagrid with combobox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox, filter

I've got a combobox that is binded with my grouped collectionview

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ContactsView"  Source="{Binding ContactsCollection }" Filter="Filter" >
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <dat:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Contact_grname" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

in code:

```
ICollectionView contactsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid1.ItemsSource);
cmbGroup.ItemsSource = contactsView.Groups;
```

The group items are correctly added in my combobox, but when I select an item in my combobox, how to filter my datagrid with that selected group?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I understood your problem correctly , but you can try the following

```
contactsview.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterFunction);

public bool FilterFunction(Object item)
{
     MyObject eachItem = item as MyObject;

    // return true if eachItem satisfies some criteria else false
}
```